# fill a 2d array in java diagonally whit loops and without abs

Tags: java, arrays

good mornig,
given the following exercise
Given the number n, not greater than 100, create a matrix of size n×n and fill it using the following rule. Numbers 0 should be stored on the primary (main) diagonal. The two diagonals, adjacent to the primary one, should contain numbers 1. The next two diagonals should contain numbers 2; etc.

Note: the primary diagonal runs from the top left corner to the bottom right corner.

```
Sample Output 1:

0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 2 3
2 1 0 1 2
3 2 1 0 1
4 3 2 1 0
is possible do with loops without abs method?

`Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("inserisci numero");
int a = s.nextInt();
        
int arr[][] = new int [a][a];
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));

        
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++ ) {
                 
int x = 0;
//here code is wrong
while (j< arr[i].length) {
                        
if (i == j) {
arr[i][j]=x;
                        }if  (j == i+x) {
                             arr[i][j] = x;
                        }
                            j++;
                            x++;
                    }
                /*} this is the principle but i can't put it on a loops
                 * if (i == j) {
                    arr[i][j]=0;
                    }if  (j == i+1) {
                     arr[i][j] = 1;
                } if  (j == i+2) {
                     arr[i][j] = 2;
                } if  (j == i+3) {
                     arr[i][j] = 3;
                } if  (i == j+1) {
                     arr[i][j] = 1;
                } if  (i == j+2) {
                     arr[i][j] = 2;
                } if  (i == j+3) {
                     arr[i][j] = 3;*/
         
             }
             
         }
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
    }`
```

Comment: You've posted some code, fine, but you forget to explain what wrong? What is the problem you've encountered?

Comment: my code didn't work, i can't figure out how to fill array diagonally using nested loops, if is possible. i tried to post what i was thiniking and tried.

Comment: *"not working"* - is not a helpful description of the failing behavior. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If your goal is to understand how to address the problem (not simply to receive a ready to go solution) then you need to apply effort explaining the logic behind the code you've written.

Comment: ok sorry, i though post my code was better than trying to explain. the task is fill an array 2d diagonally, i tried with if else because fo fill in one way i have the pattern [i][j+1], and on the other side opposite [ii+1][j], so i was trying to build a loop that can do that. but i am missing somethig.

Comment: mainly i know is possible do with abs because you work only in one side and transform the other, but i am not familiar with abs method ( i am really new in java as well), so my task is is possible do same thing by using nested loops? and i need help for build that loops, without using abs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this exercise without Math.abs, you can do in this way:

```
        int n = 5;
        int[][] matrix= new int[n][n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if(j < i){
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j] + 1;
                }else if(j == i){
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }else{
                    matrix[i][j] = j - i;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

you can place 0 when i and j are the same index. at the second (i = 1) round of second for, you have already place 0 on m[0][0], so you can use this value to place 1 under m[0][0] by adding 1 to this value. if j > i, you can place the value obtained doing j - i.

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating the task unnecessarily. Try to work with the indices. For example, if we look at the indices of the main diagonal `(i,j)` the indices are `(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)` and so on. In other words, a main diagonal element always has indexes where `i = j`. The diagonals Where ones are stored have the indices `(1,0), (2,1), (3,2)...` in the lower area and `(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)` and so on in the upper. so where the difference between i and j is 1. The same is true for the 2s. indexes with a difference of `2` such as `(2,0), (3,1), (4,2)` and so on. Use this pattern to fill your matrix

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = Math.abs(i-j);
        }
    }

    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

If, for whatever reason, you cann't use the `Math.abs()` method just check which index is greater:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(i > j){
                matrix[i][j] = i-j;
            }
            else {
                matrix[i][j] = j-i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so  much, i got the way but not how, my ming has reconize the pattern but i was not able to put on code, i tried your solution it worked, but is possible do it without abs method? or can you explain how this code work?